# In Cypress, can you call the .click() method on an Element without it identifying an error?

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

I have an Angular app that I am creating Cypress E2Es for.

A page of the app has a table in which the third column contains a link that goes by the class name 'link ng-star-inserted' that I want the test to click on after finding a specific row.

And I've actually gotten the test to do this - the link is in fact clicked.

But it's not very elegant and it flags the .click() method as an error (even though it does work).

I'm looking for a way to get it to not flag the .click() method as an error.

This is my code...

```
cy.get(SELECTOR.dataTableBody).should('be.visible')
        .contains('tr', 'Text I am looking for in the row I want')
        .then($row => {
            cy.log('found it');
            cy.log('on row ' + $row.index());

            //Yes this is kind of ugly.  I tried it every other way I could think of and this is the only way it worked
            let cellWithLink = $row.find('td:nth-child(3)');
            cellWithLink.children().get(0).getElementsByClassName('link ng-star-inserted').item(0).click();
            
});
```

And this is a shot of where the IDE flags click() as an error - even though it does actually work.

[image]

Thanks much!

Comment: What's if you remove brace bracket the end?

Comment: What's the ide think the error is?

Comment: If I remove the braces at the end it still flags it as an error and also doesn't work.

The IDE flags the error as:

Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)

Comment: You know what - Googling the error helped me find a solution. Thanks.  I didn't know that Cypress typescript values could essentially be typecast: 

let element: HTMLElement = cellWithLink.children().get(0).getElementsByClassName('link ng-star-inserted').item(0) as HTMLElement;
element.click();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the test code, the HTML looks something like

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="p-datatable-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text I am looking for in the row I want</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <span>
          <a class="link ng-star-inserted">Click me</a></td>
        </span>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Checking the `type` returned from `.getElementsByClassName()`, you can see it's an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is a ***generic collection of elements***.

```js
cy.get('table').should('be.visible')
  .contains('tr', 'Text I am looking for in the row I want')
  .then($row => {

    let cellWithLink = $row.find('td:nth-child(3)')

    const link = cellWithLink.children()
      .get(0)
      .getElementsByClassName('link ng-star-inserted')
      // .item(0)
      // .click()

    console.log(link)   // result of getElementsByClassName()
  })
```

The `item(0)` method returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which doesn't have a `.click()` method (since this type is for **all elements**, not just clickable ones)

Presuming it's the typescript checker that throws the red squiggly (and since you are running Angular), you could try type-casting to [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) which does have a `click()` method.

```
cy.get('table').should('be.visible')
  .contains('tr', 'Text I am looking for in the row I want')
  .then($row => {

    let cellWithLink = $row.find('td:nth-child(3)')
    const link = cellWithLink.children()
      .get(0)
      .getElementsByClassName('link ng-star-inserted')
      .item(0);
      // .click()

    (link as HTMLElement).click()

  })
```

[image]

---

#### Reducing the ugly

Your test is starting with Cypress queries, then shifting to jQuery queries and then using native HTML queries (starting at `.get(0)`).

If you want to keep it Cypress all the way, this should be enough:

```js
cy.get('table').should('be.visible')
  .contains('tr', 'Text I am looking for in the row I want')
  .find('td:nth-child(3)')
  .find('.link.ng-star-inserted')
  .click()
```

Comment: That worked - and it also looks  a thousand times better.  Thank you!